# Nodejs synchronicity between requests

Tags: multithreading, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, synchronous

I understand the asynchronous nature of node and async programming concepts, I have been doing it for a long time.  But I am in a situation where I need simultaneous requests to check something "in sync" if you will.  Let me explain:

- UserA requests a resource which doesn't exist.
- Set a flag for "isProcessing" to let others know the resource is being created.
- UserB requests the same resource, sees that it's processing, and waits for it to be ready (using polling - don't focus on this, as this part works the way we want)
- [a bunch of heavy async stuff happens to generate a resource]
- Resource is ready, anybody polling for it will get notified (like I said, this part works)

The part that has me in a pickle is "step 2" where we set the "isProcessing" flag.  This is an asynchronous database operation (**mongo**) which is not yet complete when 2+ requests come in **at the same time**.  As a result, multiple requests are attempting to create the same resource.  The problem goes away if the requests are separated by enough time for the database write to happen (~5ms), but not for "simultaneous" requests.

Can anybody offer some good advice to solve this.  It seems that I need to set the "isProcessing" flag in a synchronous (thread-blocking) way.  I know the file system has synchronous operations - is this the way to go?  We are using node on a multi-core machine which will scale into a cloud some day.  We are using pm2 to distribute our app across multiple cores.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the setting of the flag have to be an async database operation?  Can it be an immediate flag set in memory so thus there is no delay?

Comment: @jfriend00 - Any tips on doing this in a way that will scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the database access right. When you say

```
UPDATE MyLockTable SET IsProcessing = 1 WHERE IsProcessing = 0
```

You get 0 rows modified if IsProcessing already were set to 1. Otherwise, 1 row. This is how you can tell the two cases apart and start the heavy work only once.

Comment: I really like this and didn't even think about it.  I will test and report back (using mongodb by the way, but it returns the number of rows updated).

Comment: This ended up leading in me in the right direction.  I used a combination of unique field constraints and error handling for duplicate inserts, and this answer set me in that direction.